# Including JS in default View in Cake PHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I can do this in any of my View file in Cake PHP:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('myjs.js', false); ?>
```

but if I do the same thing in my default view (`default.ctp`) then the JS files don't load i.e. they don't get echoed.  I have tried moving includes above and below `<?php echo $scripts_for_layout ?>` in the default view but they still don't get printed:

```
<?php echo $scripts_for_layout ?>  
<?php echo $this->Html->script('myjs.js'); ?>

<?php echo $this->Html->script('myjs.js'); ?>
<?php echo $scripts_for_layout ?>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a project with scripts added just before $scripts_for_layout and they are displayed fine. The only difference is that I'm not adding the extension .js to the call, like this:

default.ctp:

```
<head>
    <?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
    <title>
        <?php echo "Site > $title_for_layout"; ?>
    </title>
<?php    
  echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.6.4');
  echo $this->Html->script('jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min');
  echo $this->Html->script('mercado');
  echo $scripts_for_layout;
?>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you.. the problem was that I had `false` as a second argument to `script(...)`.  I just left it out and it all worked fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

with or without an extension - this is not the reason why the script do not get echoed,

as **mensch** mentioned before it makes no difference because of:

source of html helper cakephp 2

```
if (strpos($url, '?') === false && substr($url, -3) !== '.js') {
  $url .= '.js';
}
```

the reason is:
 you have already inserted this script inside your view,

cake checks if the script is already inserted on the page

> options - 'once' - Whether or not the script should be checked for uniqueness. If true scripts will only be included once, use false to allow
>   the same script to be included more than once per request.

by default the value of **once** is set to TRUE

remove the script from your view first and then try it with or without '.js'

P.S.: why the **petervaz** answer has worked for you:
because this check:

```
if ($options['once'] && isset($this->__includedScripts[$url])) {
    return null;
}
```

made before check for file extension

so `isset(__includedScripts['myjs']) == false // because first key was __includedScripts['myjs.js']`

and you've got your script included

Comment: Very thorough answer! I was under the impression alemaster already used the script call without the once option set to false based on his last block of code.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing I'd DEFINITELY recommend is to check that loading your JS in a view is 100% OK with everything.

Do NOT use $this->Html->script if you are unsure about:

--- the dependency of scripts on each other

--- the dependency of some plugins on other scripts

--- how many different layouts and/or views you want to use in the future.

For example, some plugins use jQuery but they require jQuery to be loaded BEFORE the plugin itself.

So if you put jQuery in a view or layout, the plugin's JS loads before jQuery and plugin may not work. If you want to make sure some script loads first, you can try this:

in your app/View/Helper/AppHelper.php:

```
class AppHelper extends Helper {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Session');

    public function beforeRender($viewFile){
            echo $this->Html->script('jquery', array('inline'=>false));
        }
}
```

Therefore you don't have to include jQuery in multiple views and it loads first.

Answer (score 0):

`$scripts_for_layout` in a layout is a placeholder for all the scripts included in views, so if you include it or don't won't have any effect if you load scripts directly in the `default.ctp`.

That being said, adding the extension or leaving it out of the `$this->Html->script()` call shouldn't make a difference. What could be the case is that the HtmlHelper isn't called correctly (it's called by default in Cake 2.0), but you should be receiving error messages. Is debug set to 2 in `/app/Config/core.php`?